# Inverse Binomial Coefficient Lookup/Check

Tags: binomial-coefficients

Is there a quick way of checking - either by hand or computationally - whether or not a given integer is a binomial coefficient?

If there isn't, is there a website where one can check this easily?

Comment: Probably you're ignoring the coefficient ${N\choose 1} = N$, is *any* solution $N ={n \choose k}$ with $k > 1$ OK?

Comment: @pjs36 - Yes, not just the trivial cases. Not only *any* but *all* solutions if possible.

Comment: Just saw [this](http://mathoverflow.net/a/101093/67014) and was reminded of your question. Do you think it's relevant here?

Comment: @pjs36 - Thanks. Looks interesting. Have also come across that conjecture on wiki. It But it does not really allow you to check if a given number is a binomial coefficient.

Answer (score 0):

[https://oeis.org/](https://oeis.org)

For example, for ${16\choose 9}= 11440 $ the web site lists it as belonging to binomial coefficient series $C(2n, n-1)$,$C(n,7)$,$C(n,9)$.

As a general question, it looks like an interesting problem and I also could not find any reference to this general topic. However, the easiest way for me was to write a small program that checks if a certain number is a binomial coefficient or not.

Comment: [OEIS A006987](https://oeis.org/A006987) might answer the question